# Problem with LocalScroll when using on scrollable elements

Tags: jquery, plugins, scroll, scrollto

I've noticed that if you use the LocalScroll plugin with scrollable elements and you use the scroll in those elements, the behaviour sometimes looks like there's a bug.

URL with the example of the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/oms02/s53h7gko/26/

```js
$.localScroll({
    target: '#wrapper',
    axis: 'xy',
  queue:true,
  duration:1000,
  hash:false,
  lazy:true,
    onBefore:function( e, anchor, $target ){
  },
  onAfter:function( anchor, settings ){
  }
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  border:3px solid black;
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#div1 {
  width:4000px;height:500px;
  overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:auto;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:5px 0 0 5px;
}

#div2 {
  width:4000px;height:500px;
  overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:auto;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:5px 0 0 5px;
}

.box {
  float:left;
  border:1px solid green;
  width:200px;height:600px;
}

.box h2 {
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js?1.4.11"></script>
<script src="http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/localScroll/js/jquery.localscroll-min.js?1.3.4"></script>
<a href="#section2.1">go to section 2.1</a>
<br>
<a href="#section2.2">go to section 2.2</a>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="div1">
    <div class="box" id="section1.1">
      <h2>content 1.1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="section1.2">
      <h2>content 1.2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="section1.3">
      <h2>content 1.3</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="section1.4">
      <h2>content 1.4</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="section1.5">
      <h2>content 1.5</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="section1.6">
      <h2>content 1.6</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <div class="box" id="section2.1">
      <h2>content 2.1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="section2.2">
      <h2>content 2.2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="section2.3">
      <h2>content 2.3</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="section2.4">
      <h2>content 2.4</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="section2.5">
      <h2>content 2.5</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="section2.6">
      <h2>content 2.6</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Scenario:**

There's a wrapper (small size) which has inside two large scrollable divs (once upon the other) with six floated elements with a height bigger than their parents so that the user can use the scroll.
In resume, the "map" look like this:

### | 1.1 | 1.2 | 1.3 | 1.4 | 1.5 | 1.6 |

### | 2.1 | 2.2 | 2.3 | 2.4 | 2.5 | 2.6 |

**Steps:**

1. Click on the link "go to section 2.1". This correctly leads you to that div.
2. Scroll on the section and before you click on the other link, make sure the div#section2.1 is not on the top (scroll). In this case, you won't be able to see the text of the box.
3. Click on the link "go to section 2.2": on the second movement (on the y-axis) it scrolls on the whole wrapper, which is wrong because the scroll should happen on the #div2. The text of the boxes looks like hidden. If you scroll on the boxes of section 2, then you'll see the content, but you can see that the plugin didn't bring you to the correct position.

I've tried almost everything but all failed:
1. Set a margin between both elements.
2. Insert a third div between them (position relative and lower z-index).
3. Set the position of the scrolled div to the top before the movement begins.

The result is always the same: both divs looks like they both collision/crush

Any idea?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The text of the boxes looks like hidden. If you scroll on the boxes of section 2, then you'll see the content, but you can see that the plugin didn't bring you to the correct position.

The issue can be solved using the offset and onAfter callbacks:

- onAfter: save current top position for each anchor, only for the first time
- offset: compute again current top and if different (refer to scroll event) return an offset in order to compensate it

In order to compensate the scroll too you need to add into offset callback a call to scrollTop animation.

```
    $.localScroll({
            target: '#wrapper',
            axis: 'xy',
            queue: true,
            duration: 1000,
            hash: false,
            lazy: true,
            offset: function(elem, anchor) {
                var top = anchor.offset().top + $(this.target).scrollTop() - $(this.target).offset().top;
                var startPos = anchor.data('startPos');
                if (startPos != undefined && startPos != top) {
                    startPos = {top: startPos - top, left: 0};
                }
                // in order to compensate the scroll...next line
                anchor.parent().animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 10)
                return startPos;
            },
            onBefore: function (e, anchor, $target) {
            },
            onAfter: function (anchor, settings) {
                var startPos = anchor.data('startPos');
                if (startPos == undefined) {
                    var self = this;
                    anchor.siblings().addBack().each(function(idx, ele) {
                        var top = anchor.offset().top + $(self).scrollTop() - $(self).offset().top;
                        $(ele).data('startPos', top);
                    });
                }
            }
     });
```

```js
$.localScroll({
  target: '#wrapper',
  axis: 'xy',
  queue: true,
  duration: 1000,
  hash: false,
  lazy: true,
  offset: function(elem, anchor) {
      var top = anchor.offset().top + $(this.target).scrollTop() - $(this.target).offset().top;
      var startPos = anchor.data('startPos');
      if (startPos != undefined && startPos != top) {
          startPos = {top: startPos - top, left: 0};
      }
      anchor.parent().animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 10)
      return startPos;
  },
  onBefore: function (e, anchor, $target) {
  },
  onAfter: function (anchor, settings) {
      var startPos = anchor.data('startPos');
      if (startPos == undefined) {
          var self = this;
          anchor.siblings().addBack().each(function(idx, ele) {
              var top = anchor.offset().top + $(self).scrollTop() - $(self).offset().top;
              $(ele).data('startPos', top);
          });
      }
  }
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
    border: 3px solid black;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#div1 {
    width: 4000px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

#div2 {
    width: 4000px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
}

.box {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 600px;
}

.box h2 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.scrollto@2.1.2/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.localscroll@2.0.0/jquery.localScroll.min.js"></script>

<a href="#section1.1">go to section 1.1</a>
<br>
<a href="#section1.2">go to section 1.2</a>
<br>
<a href="#section1.3">go to section 1.3</a>
<br>
<a href="#section2.1">go to section 2.1</a>
<br>
<a href="#section2.2">go to section 2.2</a>
<br>
<a href="#section2.3">go to section 2.3</a>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1">
        <div class="box" id="section1.1">
            <h2>content 1.1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="section1.2">
            <h2>content 1.2</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="section1.3">
            <h2>content 1.3</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="section1.4">
            <h2>content 1.4</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="section1.5">
            <h2>content 1.5</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="section1.6">
            <h2>content 1.6</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        <div class="box" id="section2.1">
            <h2>content 2.1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="section2.2">
            <h2>content 2.2</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="section2.3">
            <h2>content 2.3</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="section2.4">
            <h2>content 2.4</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="section2.5">
            <h2>content 2.5</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="section2.6">
            <h2>content 2.6</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but that not the solution, because as you can see it completely breaks the animation movement.

Comment: @cooper Answer and snippet updated. Let me know. Thanks

Comment: I get the error: "TypeError: anchor.data is not a function" and it "crush" the animation :(

Comment: does it work in the snippet? I assume there must be a difference with your code: html or jquery libs

Comment: That's what I don't unserstand. The code is exactly the same.

Comment: take a look to the libraries I used.

Comment: After a long time I tried again. It worked perfectly. Thanks.